# How to download a list to fasta format in python?

Tags: python, biopython

I'm using google colab for begginers reason :/

```
pip install biopython
```

I opened a file to use its lines as search term later

```
lines = []

with open('my_file.seq') as f:
  lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f] 

print(lines)
```

I'm using the lines in the search space

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Entrez

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=lines, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
record_iterator = SeqIO.parse(handle, "gb")
for record in record_iterator:
  
  print(record.id, record.seq)
  

handle.close()
```

And this resturns me exactaly what i want. But how can i download it as a fasta format like the one below? Preferably with the space between them as in the example.
I have a lot of sequences to download, don't know if this information changes anything
Thanks in advance!

MZ051983.1 TTTGGTGCCTGGGCAGGAATAATTGGTACTGCCCTCAGCCTACTAATTCGAGCAGAGTTAGCCCAGCCAGGGGCCCTCCTAGGCGATGACCAGATTTATAACGTCATTGTTACTGCCCATGCCTTCGTTATAATTTTCTTTATAGTGATACCAATTATGATCGGGGGCTTTGGCAACTGACTTGTTCCACTAATAA

MZ051929.1 ACCACTCATAAAGACATTGGCACCCTATACCTAATCTTTGGTGCCTGGGCAGGAATAATTGGTACTGCCCTCAGCCTACTAATTCGAGCAGAGTTAGCCCAGCCAGGGGCCCTCCTAGGCGATGACCAGATTTATAACGTCATTGTTACTGCCCATGCCTTCGTTATAATTTTCTTTATAGTGATACCAATTATGA

Comment: `print(record.id record.seq)` is not valid Python syntax. It's not clear how you want the two pieces of code to fit together.

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot the comma. But all the things i did return me the example i put it there. I'm just having trouble downloading it

Comment: Downloading what, from where to where?

Comment: Do you mean, how can you save the output from these scripts to files you can then download? You'll have to write to a file instead of print; then try https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41381/how-to-save-google-colab-notebook-outputs-and-variables

Comment: Yes, i want to save the efetch search result in a fasta file. Oh, thanks! I'll check that one out

Comment: append the records to a list and save the list with SeqIO.write or directly save the record from the parser to file with SeqIO write

Comment: google it see: https://biopython.org/docs/1.78/api/Bio.SeqIO.html